# How to structure likes laravel

Tags: javascript

I came from laravel Php, i want to create my own object relation mappin. i tried to convert laravel php to javascript. i see other framework But i confuse how javascript can structure like php access. In laravel Model https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html. There're no first, firstWhere, find, get Method. but the method inside collection https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html.

How to make structure access like laravel? to connect model with collection? model and relationship can connect but how about collection?

in laravel

```
// Model can access collection method and return collection, 
// Then collection can access model back. then model access it relationship.
// Model have hasRelationship trait.
$colletion = Person::find(id);
return $collection->gadgets
```

person model

```
class Person extends Model
{
  public function gadgets()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(Gadget::class);
  }
}
```

i want the way access libs like laravel
person model

```
const Gadget = require('./models/gadget');

class Person Extends Model
{
  get gadgets()
  {
    return this.hasOne(Gadget);
  }
}
```

My javascript libs
model class

```
class Model extends Relationship
{
    _table;
    _primaryKey;
}

module.exports = Model;
```

collection class

```
class Collection
{
    #items;

    constructor(array)
    {
        this.#items = array;
    }

    async find(id){}
}

module.exports = Collection;
```

relationship class

```
class Relationship
{
    async hasOne(parent, relatedKey = null, parentKey = null)
    {
        const relKey = relatedKey || this._primaryKey;
        const parKey = parentKey || parent._primaryKey;

        const query = 
        `SELECT *
        FROM ${parent._table}
        WHERE ${this._table}.${relKey} = ${parent._table}.${parentKey}`;
        
        const [rows] = connection.query(query);

        return rows;
    }
}

module.exports = Relationship;
```

person class

```
const Model = require('./model');

class Person Extends Model
{
    _table = 'person';
}

module.exports = new Person;
```

Comment: What you are looking for is an ORM. I don't use ORMs and prefer query constructors instead (I use knex in node which is kind of like php-sql-query-builder). Go to npmjs.com, search "orm" and pick one you like. FYI Laravel also uses an ORM in case you are not familiar with the term

Comment: Note that in node.js frameworks are usually lightweight. The most popular web framework for example (Express) only provides a way for you to define controllers. It doesn't come with any templating language, it doesn't come with any db access or modelling, it does not even come with a way to handle POST request. You have to ability to choose any library you want to code the way you want. In a weird way, by being incomplete, node.js frameworks allow you to work exactly the way you're used to in Laravel by choosing how you want to do stuff

Comment: @slebetman u answer out of topic. i know ORM. my question to structure so the use of library like ORM. My problem is how to connect model with collection. thats it. after that i know what i;m doing next